# what it mean in logging.properties at vert.x?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging, vert.x

Here's the default logging.properties file included in Vert.x:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler,java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %6$s\n
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.VertxLoggerFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%t/vertx.log
```

What do the below statements mean?

```
.level=INFO
org.vertx.level=INFO
com.hazelcast.level=SEVERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the documentation for java.util.logging, that is used by vert.x by default.

.level=INFO turns on INFO logging for all classes, org.vertx.level=INFO turns on INFO logging for all classes in org.vertx, same for hazelcast